# Best place to store photo\video annotations data

Tags: video, photo

I know how to persist photo\video annotations data\text. The problem is what is the best place to store them?

I can create another column in the database where I store other photo info.

OR

I see some people storing them as xml in the JPEG header. Sounds weird but I might be wrong.

Any other option which might be better?

If you have experience with working with image\video annotations, please share your thoughts.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I use C# .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [EXIF](http://www.exif.org/specifications.html) tags to store some metadata about photos (JPG files) we store from various sensor arrays. Specifically, a proprietary string of data which I place in the User Comment field. You didn't mention a programming language choice, but as an example, I use the [ExifUtils library](http://www.hugsan.com/EXIFutils/) in a C# application.

I cannot comment as to best practices with video annotations.

Comment: I already have EXIF data. How big the User comments can get? Since image will store the extra text embedded inside the image, this will increase the image size. Other problem is I have to read the header every time the image is loaded. That is why I extract the EXIF info just once and store in the database.

Comment: Per the [specifications](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) on page 34 (document page 28) "The value of Count N is determined based on the 8 bytes in the character code area and the number of bytes in the user comment part." I interpret this to mean that there is not a limit to the number of bytes you can allocate to a user comment. Adding text is usually insignificant compared to the image size, but if you are going to add a *lot* of text, it is probably best to merely associate with the photo in your database.

Comment: OK. For your case, do you pull the EXIF+Annotations at client side by JS\JQuery or at server side?

Comment: @Projapati: I have a data collection program which adds the EXIF tag when the image is captured from a network camera. Data like current temperature and other sensor values are added to the tag. The tags are later read by a browsing application when users look at the history of a particular site. Thus my usage is somewhat proprietary/closed since the images are not processed by anything that employs Javascript.